# PowerShell "$g = $json | ConvertFrom-Json | Group State" result is different from "$g = $json | ConvertFrom-Json ; $g = $g | Group State ;"

Tags: powershell

Below test2 and test3 results are different.
I'm confusing about it, because it looks like same logic, and different from linux bash `||` logic.

```powershell
$data = @(
    [PSCustomObject]@{State="TAIPEI";Type="1"}
    [PSCustomObject]@{State="TAIPEI";Type="2"}
    [PSCustomObject]@{State="KH";Type="3"}
    [PSCustomObject]@{State="KH";Type="4"}
    [PSCustomObject]@{State="KH";Type="5"}
    [PSCustomObject]@{State="TX";Type="6"}
    [PSCustomObject]@{State="TX";Type="7"}
)

$json = $data | ConvertTo-Json ;

# test1
$g = $data | Group State;
Write-Host($g.Length); #result : 3

# test2
$g = $json | ConvertFrom-Json | Group State ;
Write-Host($g.Length); #result : 1 

# test3
$g = $json | ConvertFrom-Json ;
$g = $g | Group State ;
Write-Host($g.Length); #result : 3
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##lZDLCsJADEX38xWhdqELhVof4CAo4ltQsKAgLqqGqtROmUkVUb@91kdFV63ZhRzODdcXJ5Rqi64bhvrGJhvq0MgyiGYxmbYCReIwXu1xTcvGZUo2YV2zmv1Ju69x6@xHm6Hd/sGLSfiwF6NmerSUHi0n/juP0Up6tBqhOcb0vRJeVOGryiu0hHdESZbIDx4HzlgGCBUZTHe@sK4UgQ9PKWczuSPM94SirO4URug5tM1xyEhUgUtQAzO2FN@WZ@gnrCPF4RX3I4YUZgNitZmg5u@783@ICWF4Bw)

What I've tried :
I use vscode debug mode check the varible

test1 it's [Object[3]] and 3 GroupInfo
[image]

test2 it become Collection
[image]

test3 it's [Object[3]] and 3 GroupInfo
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I first tried your example in Powershell 7 but couldn't reproduce your results, everything behaved as expected. So this appears to be behavior limited to Powershell 5.

Looking at what gets output from `ConvertFrom-Json` in the two versions you can see what's going on:

In Powershell 7:

```
   # ~>  $json | ConvertFrom-Json | get-member

   TypeName: System.Management.Automation.PSCustomObject
```

In Powershell 5.1:

```
# ~> $json | ConvertFrom-Json | Get-Member

   TypeName: System.Object[]
```

So it looks like in Powershell 5.1 `ConvertFrom-Json` does not output `PSCustomObject` which `Group-Object` need to function properly. I have found a simple workaround to cast the output from `ConvertFrom-Json` to `PSCustomObject` works:

```
# ~> $g = $json | ConvertFrom-Json | %{[PsCustomObject]$_} | group state
# ~> $g

Count Name                      Group
----- ----                      -----
    2 TAIPEI                    {@{State=TAIPEI; Type=1}, @{State=TAIPEI; Type=2}}
    3 KH                        {@{State=KH; Type=3}, @{State=KH; Type=4}, @{State=KH; Type=5}}
    2 TX                        {@{State=TX; Type=6}, @{State=TX; Type=7}}
```

Or you can just move to Powershell 7.